# thrift programming problem

Tags: sockets, thrift

hi
i just start programming with thrift api . i run a sample code but i dont know how to run thrift program.  i just did following :

code;

```
{#!/usr/local/bin/thrift --gen cpp

namespace cpp Test

service Something {
  i32 ping()
}
```

than run command 
thrift --gen cpp your_thrift_file.thrift

it generate seven file in a folder name gen-cpp which are following:

```
Something.cpp
Something.h

Something_server.skeleton.cpp
your_thrift_file_constants.cpp
your_thrift_file_constants.h
your_thrift_file_types.cpp
your_thrift_file_types.h
```

now i compile them all together to get executable by following command

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c Something.cpp -o something.o
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c Something_server.cpp -o server.o
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c your_thrift_file_constants.cpp -o constants.o
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c your_thrift_file_types.cpp -o types.o
```

than i write a client code  which is following

```
{  #include "Something.h"  // As an example

#include <transport/TSocket.h>
#include <transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

using namespace Test;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
  boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
  boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

  SomethingClient client(protocol);
  transport->open();
  client.ping();
  transport->close();

  return 0;
}
```

now than i compile it with command

> g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c something_client.cpp -o client.o

and than make the executable by following command

> g++ -L/usr/local/lib -lthrift client.o Something.o constants.o types.o -o Something_client

But when i run it it shows following error

> command: ./Somthing_client
>   result:Thrift: Fri May 20 10:49:17 2011 TSocket::open() connect() Connection refused
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
>     what():  connect() failed: Connection refused
>   Aborted

now i don't understand what I'm doing wrong?
can anybody explain me thrift working ?
how to run this code properly ?
what is this code doing ?

Comment: You have been here for a while now. It's annoying that you do not take some time and format your question properly. If you can't even do that, why should we answer your question?

Comment: pal just tell me the format, consider me as a callow or novice  person & give me exact step or writing method so that i can get answers please don't tell me or give me some hyper-link for this

Comment: imho, someone that has been a member for 9 months and asked 40 questions is not a novice. Have you never noticed that your questions look terrible after you have written then? Haven't you seen the toolbar just above the textbox that you write your questions in? Try putting the mouse above each icon to see what they do.

Comment: man realy dont know what are u talking abut . what icon u are talking about,i never saw them , Please give me proper information, tell me about my mistake , style of asking question , all i try to do is put more and more information in question , ya i'm very weak at english

Answer (score 1):

Is your Thrift server running too?  The client needs something to connect to. The error looks like there's no open socket on port 9090 (set in your code).